# ServiceStack.net Session End Event or Callback?

Tags: .net, session, session-timeout, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack.Net with authentication and am using a custom session, all working great.

I'd like to know if there is an event or callback, override or any other mechanism to know when a session has ended (i.e. the client drops), or when the session expires?

Something like global.asax "Session_End"

Thanks.

Comment: I should point out what I'm trying to do here is record the start/end times for an authenticated user session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope there's no **Session End** event since it's impossible to determine when a session is removed from any of the backing [Cache Providers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) that could be used to cache the session.

So you shouldn't really try to rely on this, you can determine if it's expired (or really no longer exists) if they were assigned an existing session but now no longer exists, e.g:

```
var hadSessionWithId = httpReq.GetSessionId();
var existingSession = Cache.Get<TUserSession>(SessionExtensions.SessionKey);
if (hadSessionWithId ?? existingSession == null) //Existing session invalidated.
```

Comment: But where would I put this code snipe, since there is no reliable event to fire? Do I put it in a timer and check it upon timer_ticked event or something?

Comment: If you use .NET 4 or above, I suggest System.Runtime.Caching http://bartwullems.blogspot.com.au/2011/02/caching-in-net-4.html It gives you Session sliding and expire callback.